# Join the value of an entity having two records

Tags: mysql

I have two tables such as: 
phone(id,phone_number,name)
person(id,lastname,firstname)

I created a JOIN query that will list the records having phone numbers. the I got this output:

```
 last_name  |  first_name  | phone_number  | name  
------------+--------------+---------------+-------
 Smith      | John         | (415)283-9518 | Home
 Rocky      | William      | (408)842-9974 | Home
 Gomez      | Jet          | (408)293-2643 | Home
 Benson     | Seth         | (415)663-1513 | Home
 Charles    | Christopher  | (909)452-8754 | Home
 Smith      | John         | (510)534-0873 | Mobile
```

As you can notice I have duplicate record with two numbers (Smith John). Now I wanted to create a query that will remove the duplicate and list the two phone_numbers like this:

```
 last_name  |  first_name  | phone_number  | name  
------------+--------------+---------------+-------
 Smith      | John         | (415)283-9518 | Home
            |              | (510)534-0873 | Mobile
 Rocky      | William      | (408)842-9974 | Home
 Gomez      | Jet          | (408)293-2643 | Home
 Benson     | Seth         | (415)663-1513 | Home
 Charles    | Christopher  | (909)452-8754 | Home
```

Is this possible? TIA.

Comment: did you tried doing a `group by`?

Comment: @Rahul: Group by will not get the result OP is looking for. OP wants last_name and first_name to be empty for duplicate records.

Comment: yes I tried it but it gives me the first output because I need to include all the columns in the group by which results to first output.  @Rahul

Comment: yes you're right @RagingBull how can I come up with that output?

Comment: @johnigneel: Please show us your query

Comment: SELECT p.lastname,p.firstname,m.phone_number,m.name
FROM person as p
INNER JOIN phone as m ON p.id=m.id; @RagingBull

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234403/how-to-group-a-couple-of-rows-in-sql-server) a couple days ago.  I didn't flag this question since an answer hasn't been accepted on the other one yet.